# OSStatus error -67028 When Building Ad Hoc iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, build

I'm getting an error when trying to do an archive build for ad hoc distribution on iOS for an iPhone-only app. The app is signed with the proper certificates and has the proper provisioning profile (checked with a friend who was able to sign properly as well, so it's not a code signing issue).

[image]

Whenever I try to distribute with the Xcode archive panel, I get the following error message in an alert sheet:

```
OSStatus error -67028
```

I've never encountered this error before. I'm able to build and have the app run fine in both the simulator and device, but for whatever reason, I'm completely unable to get the distribution feature of Xcode to work to create an ad hoc build.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Things I've checked are:

- Code signing (generated all new certs and profiles to start from scratch)
- Files and frameworks

[image]

The only thing that I could find with the files and frameworks that might be off is that the main Storyboard file (`Main_iPhone.storyboard`) couldn't be found in the Copy Bundle Resources, although the storyboard loads properly in Xcode and allows editing, and can be found in the Finder under the `Base.lproj` folder.

Comment: maybe try removing the storyboard from the project and re-adding it.  be sure to save a copy of the project (in source control or just copy it) before messing around too much.  Also, take care when re-adding the storyboard to identify it in the plist (use the general tab, deployment info section on the target settings), and copy it to the bundle in the build phases tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/Reference/reference.html), 67028 means "The bundle format is unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable". That is pretty vague, so I would investigate the current lead you have, that is, ensure that the Main_iPhone.storyboard file is indeed in the compiled bundle. If not, check your "copy files" build phase to ensure it is there.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The issue was related to the HockeyApp integration that was causing the header file to not be found during the release build.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what part of the integration was causing this?

Comment: Hi Coney, could you elaborate the way you fixed the issue as I face the same thing @coryb

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with the HockeyApp SDK. What I actually did was

1. Remove HockeyApp SDK by selecting "Remove reference" from the Frameworks folder.
2. Drag&Drop the Folder HockeySDK.embeddedframework to the XCode Frameworks folder
3. Deselect the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)"
4. Select "Create groups for any added folders"
5. Select your target

Comment: I am not sure I can follow: so you actually repeated the steps again? Did you do anything differently the first time?

Comment: Yes. For the first time I've dragged and dropped the SDK into the Frameworks folder and selected "Copy items..." although they were there. I've also had "Create folder references ...." selected by default which might lead to the Error code, So I've repeated those steps above and it worked

Comment: I had the same error when archiving a Mac App. Removing and re-adding the 3rd party framework helped (in my case Dropbox.framework)

Comment: I had the same exact problem and was really frustrated by it. The error number was basically useless and there are so many settings I thought could be causing the problem. This took care of the issue in a few minutes. Thanks!