# OSStatus Error -67028

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build

For 2 days now I'm trying to upload a App through xcode to apple. But on every validation it shows following error:

[image]

It just came from no where. Even my older Archives that are already in the App Store show the same error when I try to validate them.

Any help would be very nice. Atm I can't push updates..

Comment: errSecCSBadBundleFormat: The bundle format is unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable.

Comment: @trojanfoe I know this error but I didn't changed anything...

Comment: And as I said even my other archives that I already could submit before, are not working anymore...

Comment: Is HockeyApp involved?

Comment: No it isn't, I just don't what the problem is..

Comment: I know there are recent changes WRT codesigning (v1 must now be v2) but I thought that only affected Mac Apps.  I think if it effected iOS apps too there would be hundreds of questions about it on here.

Comment: I don't know what you mean..

Comment: There have been recent changes to Mac App codesigning, but I don't *think* that's got anything to do with your issue.

Comment: damn <.< Any other idea?

Comment: Xcode is not recognizing bundle in your project anymore, may be you are using newer xcode...may be post a screenshot of your files for us to see...I have had this error before. which Xcode version are you using?....also ...Make sure the 'Executable Name' (CFBundleExecutable) entry in your target's info.plist matches the 'Product Name' specified in your target settings.

Comment: Product Name & CFBundleExecutable are the same.. I have to recheck all files but I don't think there's one missing...

Comment: Please post XCode version, and has that version changed since last successful upload?

Comment: It's 5.1.1, I think it has something to do with xcode 6 beta. I opened it once with it and after that problems started. Other Projects can be submitted just fine. Even older archives that I already have submitted are failing the validation now.

Comment: It's crazy. I made a new clean Project but when signing the assets it crash again...

Comment: Has anyone got a fix on this? Happening to me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it to work:

1. Click on your Project and switch between your Targets. There's a Project Target and a Target with the App Icon.
2. On Every Targets go to Build Settings and choose your Provisioning Profile and Code Signing Certificates.
3. Check under Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources if there is a Framework in there that belongs to the Library Phase.

Before all that I updated to the newest beta of Yosemite (not needed if you don't have it) and made a clean Project. Please check all these steps!

Hope it helps others!

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried the answer in this post?
[OSStatus error -67028 When Building Ad Hoc iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586991/osstatus-error-67028-when-building-ad-hoc-ios-app)

ensure that the Main_iPhone.storyboard file is indeed in the compiled bundle. If not, check your "copy files" build phase to ensure it is there.